# finding whether a string has only signed numbers in it: java - Regex

Tags: java, regex

I have a string which should contains only signed numbers. example: -100, +300, -500, 56.9, -98.6 etc

I have been trying to find the most efficient way in java to verify if the string contains only signed decimal numbers.

I apologize for the direct question.

I first did a try catch block but that would require one extra cycle every time there is a number format exception. So I was hoping to get a regular expression, as I was told these are pretty efficient.

Thanks.

Comment: What is "signed" about 300, 500, 56.9?

Comment: Also, is it about finding? or an efficient way to do so? If so, what have you tried so far?

Comment: we like "direct" questions, why apologizing?

Comment: I first did a try catch block but that would require one extra cycle every time there is a number format exception. So I was hoping to get a regular expression, as I was told these are pretty efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the imports below you can iterate numerals in the string with a regular expression.

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
```

An example of how this might be done is below.

```
final String input = "-100,+300,-500,56.9,-98.6";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile( "[+-][0-9]+.?[0-9]*" );
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher( input );
while ( matcher.find() ) {
    System.out.println( matcher.group( 0 ) );
}
```

One question raised though is internationalization. In some countries the decimal place `.` is reversed, so *1,000.00* becomes *1.000,00*. It could be a problem with your current delimiter character.

Answer (score 0):

It's trivial:

Split your input String on commas (and spaces).

Then trim each String you got
(if you split on spaces too, this is not needed).

Check if each String you got starts with + or -.
If so, all your numbers are 'signed'.
Otherwise, you have at least one 'unsigned'.

Comment: Yes, but i was hoping was something in the form of a regex.

Comment: so i would do something like: str.matched("[+-][0-9.]+")?

Comment: If you split it first, yes, otherwise you will need to use a Pattern and Matcher.

Comment: I can but I prefer not to. Want to leave something for you.